# How to verify that function passed as argument called in dart unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, dart, mockito-dart

I have following function

```
Future<T> execute<T>(Future<T> Function(ApiService apiService) getFromRemote,
      {Future<void> Function(T data) cacheData, Future<T> Function() getFromCache}) {
}
```

And I want to verify that cacheData function is called in following test

```
CacheDataFunction mockCacheDataFunction;
setUpAll(() {
  mockCacheDataFunction = CacheDataFunction();
});
test('caches value provided in future', () async {
  await repositoryRequestExecutor.execute<int>(
    (_) => Future.value(testValue),
    cacheData: (data) => mockCacheDataFunction<int>(data),
    getFromCache: () => Future.value(testValueFromCache),
  );
  verify(mockCacheDataFunction<int>(testValue));
});
```

So I made such a mock

```
class CacheDataFunction extends Mock{
  Future<void> call<T>(T data) => Future.value();
}
```

But it throws Used on a non-mockito object error. How can I achieve it?

Comment: `Mock`s should always be used as `class CacheDataFunction extends Mock {}` with no implementation.  Implementing methods in it is an anti-pattern since it undermines the ability for the `Mock` to do its usual things.

Comment: @jamesdlin well I know, I found this solution on stackoverflow but it doesn't work. That is just what I tried to do